# Postgres columns of latitude and longitude from varchar to numeric

Tags: postgresql-9.3, type-conversion

I have a table with latitude and longitude columns and they are in varchar. I have to convert them to numeric because that is how the fields are in the master table.

Is there a way to change all the values in the columns at one time from varchar to numeric in PostgreSQL?

I am struggling because since they are lat/long values they vary in length, have decimals and the longitude is negative.

Table Name

```
Latitude      | Longitude
+-----------------------------+

35.0528620000 | -119.375136000
+-------------|---------------+
```

and they go on like this. I have tried ALTER TABLE, but that just gives me an an error, CAN NOT BE CAST
and I tried http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-formatting.html 
to_char

EDIT: I was able to get the fields almost to the same length. Latitude is not 13 char and Longitude is 14 including the negative sign.

EDIT: The alter table error in Navicat:

```
[Err] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ALTER"
LINE 1: EXPLAIN ALTER TABLE "allwells_CA_copy"
```

In Postgres:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "ALTER" LINE 1: ..., VERBOSE off, COSTS on, BUFFERS off, TIMING off )ALTER TABL... ^ ********** Error ********** ERROR: syntax error at or near "ALTER" SQL state: 42601 Character: 71
```

I've been switching between PG Admin and Navicat in an attempt to make the change.

Comment: **Always** include the **exact text** of any error message and where possible the SQL that produced it.

Comment: Here is the original ALTER table error. I tried so many things yesterday with so many errors. I made an edit above

Comment: and the SQL that produced that error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `USING` clause to `ALTER TABLE ... TYPE ...`, e.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
  ALTER COLUMN "Longitude" TYPE NUMERIC(14, 11) 
    USING ("Longditude"::NUMERIC(14,11)),
  ALTER COLUMN "Latitude" TYPE NUMERIC(14, 11) 
    USING ("Latitude"::NUMERIC(14,11));
```

assuming you want a `numeric` with precision 14 and scale 11 and your columns really do have an upper case first letter.

For more details [see the manual on `ALTER TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html).

*after edit*:

You seem to be using a broken client that's trying to prepend an `EXPLAIN` to the `ALTER TABLE`. You can't `EXPLAIN` an `ALTER TABLE` statement.

Comment: I wrote something similar to this but I keep getting an error right at the 'ALTER' line 1. With your code the error is:                                                      `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ALTER"
LINE 1: ..., VERBOSE off, COSTS on, BUFFERS off, TIMING off )ALTER TABL...
                                                             ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "ALTER"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 71`

Comment: You appear to be attempting to `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` an `ALTER TABLE`. You can't `EXPLAIN` an `ALTER TABLE`. Just run it without the `EXPLAIN (...)`.

Answer (score 0):

## GIS

You shouldn't be storing lat/long as numeric, nor varchar. Use PostGIS and store them as a `GEOGRAPHY`. This allows you to do intersection tests on an index, find all points within X-range, aggregate into lines, or polygons -- and a lot more.

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
BEGIN;
  ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN geog geography;
  UPDATE foo SET geog = ST_MakePoint(long, lat);
  CREATE INDEX on foo USING gist ( geog );
  ALTER TABLE foo DROP COLUMN long, DROP COLUMN lat;
COMMIT;
```